# How do I copy over values in a matrix that surpass a threshold and set the rest of the matrix to 0?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

In MATLAB, I have a 5 x5 matrix, such as this one below:

```
>> a = rand(5)

a =

    0.9356    0.9534    0.0282    0.4752    0.7735
    0.2701    0.4514    0.9733    0.8899    0.5671
    0.7472    0.7413    0.1240    0.9107    0.8378
    0.1031    0.6197    0.5289    0.0056    0.3798
    0.0409    0.6538    0.7813    0.4902    0.2815
```

I'd like to keep those values that surpass a threshold and copy them over into a new matrix while setting the other values to 0.

This is what I've tried.  I tried generating a `logical` matrix and then indexing into the matrix to select out the values I want:

```
>> b=a>=0.30550

ans =

     1     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     1     1     0

>> a(b)

ans =

    0.9356
    0.7472
    0.9534
    0.4514
    0.7413
    0.6197
    0.6538
    0.9733
    0.5289
    0.7813
    0.4752
    0.8899
    0.9107
    0.4902
    0.7735
    0.5671
    0.8378
    0.3798
```

However, this produces a 1D vector.  How can I achieve what I want so that the output looks like this?

```
0.9356    0.9534    0         0.4752    0.7735
0         0.4514    0.9733    0.8899    0.5671
0.7472    0.7413    0         0.9107    0.8378
0         0.6197    0.5289    0         0.3798
0         0.6538    0.7813    0.4902    0
```

Comment: please mention and specify in the tags the language / framework you are using. It will be easier for people that can help to notice your question

Comment: sorry sir, i am using matlab for the purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the output as 1D vector is because when using logical indexing in a 2D array and seeing what the output is, the elements that are true in the input logical index are placed into a single column and the elements are populated by going through the matrix column-wise and searching for those values that are true.  The corresponding locations are copied over into a vector.

If it is your desire to copy over values while maintaining the shape of the matrix, you must first create an output array of zeroes, then use `logical` indexing to copy over the relevant values into the right places:

```
b = zeros(size(a));
b(a >= 0.30550) = a(a >= 0.30550);
```

The effect is that logical indexing here will allow the elements on the right side of the expression copy over in the corresponding same spatial locations on the left hand side, thus completing what you're after.

---

## Example Run

```
>> rng(123);
>> a = rand(5);
>> b = zeros(5);
>> b(a >= 0.30550) = a(a >= 0.30550);
>> a

a =

    0.6965    0.4231    0.3432    0.7380    0.6344
    0.2861    0.9808    0.7290    0.1825    0.8494
    0.2269    0.6848    0.4386    0.1755    0.7245
    0.5513    0.4809    0.0597    0.5316    0.6110
    0.7195    0.3921    0.3980    0.5318    0.7224

>> b

b =

    0.6965    0.4231    0.3432    0.7380    0.6344
         0    0.9808    0.7290         0    0.8494
         0    0.6848    0.4386         0    0.7245
    0.5513    0.4809         0    0.5316    0.6110
    0.7195    0.3921    0.3980    0.5318    0.7224
```